# Publish_actions permission upload photo?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to upload photo to users profile by using publish_actions permission.

is it possible ?

I have seen many apps using publish_actions permission to upload photo.

I tried me/photos its giving error

"user_photos permission needed."

Example : http://almightyapps.club/name/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tried to do a GET request to the Graph API. In order to GET photos, you need to use the `user_photos` permission with the `/me/photos` endpoint. If you want to publish/upload photos, you need to do a POST request to the `/me/photos` endpoint - with the `publish_actions` permission.

Btw, you need to read about Login Review too - just in case you don´t know about it yet: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review